# How to format a sentence in seam

Tags: html, jsf, seam

I am trying to format this HTML sentence `<span>X<sup>2</sup> + Y<sup>2</sup> = ____</span>` using `<s:formatText/>`. But the string `"____"` is not formatted correctly. How to get the sentence as Xpow(2) + Ypow(2) = `_____` after formatting.

Note: I have surrounded the *_*_ with an apostrophe so that it is show in the stackoverflow editor properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the _ is a special character, used for underlining. You could try escaping it:

```
\_\_
```